# Realtime desktop capturing Mac OS X Mojave and X11

Tags: c++, macos, x11, desktop, screencast

I'm working on project which streams desktop image from Mac OS X computer to iOS device in realtime. My main problem is the **screen capture**. **I'm not allowed** to use ready libraries, which allow to write some lines of code in 5 mins and stream video over the World. 
I've found a really good thing on GitHub which gets image of the whole screen using X11 and C++ :

https://github.com/Butataki/cpp-x11-make-screenshot

I've tested this code on my Ubuntu and everything works like a charm : it takes about 12ms just to capture 1 frame without saving data, and about 25ms with encoding to .jpg and saving on the disk.

To be able to build it, I've had done this :

```
$ sudo apt install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libx11-dev
```

, changed 'true' to 'TRUE' in those lines :

```
//(screenshot.cpp : 232,233 lines)
jpeg_set_quality (&cinfo, quality, TRUE);
jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);
```

and changed `Z_BEST_COMPRESSION` to `PNG_Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION`

The problem is that I did almost the same operations in my XCode (Mac OS Mojave 10.14), downloaded and linked all necessary libraries, ran executable and finally....I got a blank image. No errors occured, everything works 'fine' and saves .jpg image in my folder on desktop.

Then I figured out that X11 has a something called the 'root window', which covers all of the desktop and you can just find this window and capture everyting on your screen. But I think it's true for Ubuntu, not for my Mac.

Actually, there is something about 'root window' in this article, but I just can't fix anything :
https://finkers.wordpress.com/running-x11/#intro.rootless

P.S If it's not a good way, maybe there are some another ways to acomplish my task (realtime screencapturing on Mac OS)?

Comment: The API you need are in Quartz (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services?language=objc), specifically, look at `CGDisplayStream` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdisplaystreamref?language=objc)

Comment: @TheNextman, okay, I have found this :
[link](https://github.com/diederickh/screen_capture/blob/master/src/test/test_mac_api_research.m)
What I have done is added for-loop in place where I should be able to interact with pixels:
`for(int i = 0; i < output_width * output_height; i++)`
and I also placed if-check inside this loop : 
`if (pix[i] != 0)
   cout << "Non 0!\n";`
But there are no "Non 0!\n" line in the output. I suppose that all pixels are black. How can I fix this??
'Frame' isn`t NULL, and 'pix' pointer has non NULL address.

Comment: I tried your link with the same modifications as you, and I get some valid pixel data back. Did you check the value of output_width and output_height?

Comment: Wow, thank you for your response! No, I didn't. But I'll try as soon as I get back to my PC :). Should I enter my screen resolution instead of given in the code? And, yeah, I forgot to say that I'm using VirtualBox. Maybe that's matters.

Comment: I have used `CGDisplayStream` in VirtualBox before, and it worked well...

Comment: @TheNextman, Yeah, you are ablosolutely right! Now it works fine. All I had to do is to set my own resolution :) But wait! What if I want to set 720p/360p instead pf 1080p (my screen resolution is 1920x1080) ? How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Try using the property `kCGDisplayStreamDestinationRect`

Comment: @TheNextman Hello again. I've been trying to understand for a long time why this method is showing 16 ms when I'm moving my mouse around, and 80-130ms when I`m idle? Do you know why it's so slow? How can I fix that?

Comment: You can try specifying the key `kCGDisplayStreamMinimumFrameTime` if you need a minimum frame rate. I expect the surface is only updating when something actually changes.

Comment: @TheNextman, yeah, I tried to set min FPS this night. I found that I should set FPS in format 1.0/minFPS. And, yep, FPS is not bigger that min (even with 1 FPS), but delay fluctuates anyway. I think your idea about updating is really makes sence. I probably should place an UIImage on form and then test it. Thank u again :)